# Invariants of primary groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, p-groups

In Kaplansky's book "Infinite Abelian Groups", an abelian group $G$ is called **primary** if every element has order power of $p$ for some fixed prime number $p$. It is well-known that every divisible subgroup is a direct summand. From this, $G$ is called **reduced** if $\{0\}$ is the only divisible subgroup of $G$. I wonder how to prove the following question, which is Kaplansky's Exercise 37:

Let $G$ be a reduced primary group. Then $G/pG$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. We denote by $f(G)$ the dimension of $G/pG$, which is a cardinal number. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. How to prove that $f(H)\leqslant f(G)$ and $f(G/H)\leqslant f(G)$?

Note that if $G$ is the Prüfer $p$-group $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}(p)$, then $f(G)=0<f(H)=1$. Hence the considition "reduced" is necessary. If $G$ is a finite abelian group, then the question is easy to anwser since $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

But we are working on infinite abelian groups. I have no idea in this case.

Any comments and suggestions are welcome. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: The inequality $f(G/H)\le f(G)$ is trivial, you'd better focus on $f(H)\le f(G)$.

Comment: You are right. The quotient map $G\to G/H\to (G/H)/p(G/H)$ induces a surjective map $G/pG\to (G/H)/p(G/H)$. Hence $f(G/H)\leqslant f(G)$ is trivial. Thanks!